# Can a creature with an immunity to the prone condition still choose to go prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, immunities, prone

Can a creature with immunity to the prone condition **voluntarily** go prone, such as a ghost that wants to impose disadvantage on ranged attacks against it?

If so, does such a creature who went prone in this way still suffer from the **negative effects** of being prone: moving at half speed, spending half their speed to get up, and having disadvantage on attack rolls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had a similar question come up in a campaign I was running recently. I had to house rule it a no. Immunity isn't voluntary so a ghost cannot go prone just as a Paladin PC with divine health can't voluntarily become infected with lycanthropy. I look at it like the immortal man who wants to die but can't. The mind may try but the physical form can't actually make it happen.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Regarding your Divine Health analogy, Divine Health makes paladins immune to disease - but lycanthropy is a curse, not a disease.

Comment: Ah that is apparently true now. I hadn't looked at the 5e pal close enough to notice that they had changed the wording on divine health. I was operating on 3.5 where lycanthropy was specifically mentioned as an immunity. But your definitely right 5e tag means my analogy is no longer true.

Answer (score 6):

## No, they cannot voluntarily go prone.

The *prone* condition requires a creature to have an "top side" (head) and a "bottom side" (feet). This "bottom side" must physically interact with the ground to move the creature effectively, while moving any other way (like crawling) is less effective.

> Combatants often find themselves lying on the ground, either because they are knocked down or because they throw themselves down.

If you cannot knock a creature down (because you cannot physically interact with it, like a ghost, or the creature has no top or bottom side, like a slime) it's unable to become prone.

The item description of *ball bearings* include:

> As an action, you can spill these tiny metal balls from their pouch to cover a level area 10 feet square. A creature moving across the covered area must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall prone.

And the description of the spell *sleet storm* includes:

> The ground in the area is covered with slick ice, making it difficult terrain. When a creature enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, it falls prone.

That means the creature must physically interact with the ground to be able to go prone. If a creature never interacts with the ground, because it's naturally levitating or magically hovering, it cannot go prone.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This is not true. Flying creatures can also go prone.